# Content-Type header being removed from request

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using okhttp3 and retrofit2 to send requests and I have an interceptor that adds headers:

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
        .addHeader("Content-Type2", "*")
        .addHeader("3Content-Type2", "*")
        .addHeader("Host", "blabla.com")
        .build()

    return chain.proceed(request)
}
```

I added both chuckerInterceptor and HttpLoggingInterceptor to my okhttp client.
in the HttpLoggingInterceptor I do see my header as I set it. in the chuckerInterceptor I do not and I recieve a response matching a request with that missing header (I do see the Content-Type2 and 3Content-Type2 headers). 
I made that request in postman with and without the Content-Type header and with the header I get what I expect - some short plain text. without the header I get what I'm getting from the okhttp client - some html code.

My question is what could be removing the header? I have no other interceptor other then the loggers.

this is my client:

```
val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.level = (HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        val cookieManager = CookieManager()
        val chuckerCollector = ChuckerCollector(
            context = MainActivity.context,
            showNotification = true,
            retentionPeriod = RetentionManager.Period.ONE_HOUR
        )

        val chuckerInterceptor = ChuckerInterceptor.Builder(MainActivity.context)
            .collector(chuckerCollector)
            .maxContentLength(250_000L)
            .redactHeaders("Auth-Token", "Bearer")
            .alwaysReadResponseBody(true)
            .build()

        cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL)
        val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .addInterceptor(HeadersInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(chuckerInterceptor)
            .build()
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
        interface = retrofit.create(interface::class.java)
```

I also tried adding this

```
    .addNetworkInterceptor(Interceptor { chain ->
        val originalRequest = chain.request()
        val modifiedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
            .build()
        chain.proceed(modifiedRequest)
    })
```

Comment: can you share interface where you have mentioned api methods along with end points

Comment: sure, added the interface + endpoints

Comment: have tried to replace ```addHeader``` method with ```header``` ?

Comment: yea, same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `RequestBody` class defines a content type, that’ll be used instead of any header you set on the `Request`. If you don’t like that, install your interceptor as a network interceptor and it’ll take precedence.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/http/BridgeInterceptor.kt#L43

Comment: added this: 
`.addNetworkInterceptor(Interceptor { chain ->
                val originalRequest = chain.request()
                val modifiedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
                    .build()
                chain.proceed(modifiedRequest)
            })`

to my okhttp client but it didn't help, in chucker UI I still don't see this header.

also I send string not RequestBody

Comment: But I just tried the link u sent and it did work. thanks!
can you explain what you said about the header being removed, and why it happened even using String?